# What's the difference between `visible?` and `present?`?

Tags: watir

From the Watir API, I've derived two assertions (which of course might not be correct):

- I can use `exists?` if I simply want to verify that the element is in the HTML. I don't care if it's visible or not.
- I can use `visible?`if I want to be able to see it on the page.

So, when do I use `present?`?

It seems to me that I could answer my own question by saying:

- I can use `present?` if I want to be able to see it on the page, but I don't want it to be in the HTML.

So, if I write something on the screen using a marker pen, would that be `present?`?

(Sorry if I seem to be irreverent.)

So - another way to ask the question in the title - when should I use `visible?` and when should I use `present?`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between `visible?` and `present?` is when the element does not exist in the HTML.

When the element is not in the HTML (ie `exists?` is false):

- `visible?` will throw an exception.
- `present?` will return false.

I tend to stick with `present?` since I only care if a user can see the element. I do not care if it cannot be seen due to it being hidden via style, eg `display:none;`, or not being in the DOM, eg it got deleted. I would only use `visible?` if the application actually treats the element not being in the DOM as a different meaning than being in the DOM but not visible.

For example, given the page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="1" style="display:block;">This text is displayed</div>
    <div id="2" style="display:none;">This text is not displayed</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see the difference when looking for a div that is not on the page:

```
browser.div(:id => '3').visible?
#=> Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException

browser.div(:id => '3').present?
#=> false
```

For elements on the page, the two methods will be the same:

```
browser.div(:id => '1').visible?
#=> true
browser.div(:id => '1').present?
#=> true

browser.div(:id => '2').visible?
#=> false
browser.div(:id => '2').present?
#=> false
```

A comparison of these two methods along with `exists?` can be found in the [Watirways book](https://leanpub.com/watirways/read#leanpub-auto-existence).

Comment: The combination of this post, and the description given in "Watirways" provides a complete answer for me.

Comment: Note that the plan for Watir v7.0 is to make `#visible?` behave the exact same as `#present?`.

Comment: What would you use to verify if the element is available in DOM HTML and not in the UI page.

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan, you would use `#exists?`.