# ElementNotVisibleError - A Specific Watir-Webdriver Issue

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

Trying to do

```
b.select_list(:name => "bedroomsMin").select '3+ Beds'
```

on

```
<div class="beds col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control wide" name="bedroomsMin">
            <option value="null">All Beds</option>
            <option value="0">0+ Beds</option>
            <option value="1">1+ Beds</option>
            <option value="2">2+ Beds</option>
            <option value="3">3+ Beds</option>
            <option value="4">4+ Beds</option>
            <option value="5">5+ Beds</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

but get the following error:

```
element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError).
```

This list selector is contained in a dropdown element that is clicked like this:

```
b.link(:class => 'btn-open-filers').when_present.click
```

How can I select if it's not visible? Is there a way to force visibility?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a timing issue. When the link is clicked, the dialog containing the select list may not appear before Watir tries to interact with it.

Try waiting for the select list:

```
b.select_list(:name => "bedroomsMin").when_present.select '3+ Beds'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `<div class="beds col-sm-2 hidden-xs">` having hidden may have something to do with it.

Also it appears you're are only checking for when the element is present, which is to say if it loads in the html but is not *visible* it'll still return true.

Here's a quick read on that:

[What's the difference between `visible?` and `present?`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877525/whats-the-difference-between-visible-and-present)

Since you have it clicking the dropdown after it checks for it's presence, there might be a timing issue.  In which case it may check that the dropdown is present in the DOM but is not actually opening the dropdown.

May want to try something like:

```
dropdown = b.link(:class => 'btn-open-filers')
dropdown.click if dropdown.visible?
b.select_list(:name => "bedroomsMin").select '3+ Beds'
```

Answer (score 0):

Watir is designed to interact with the elements that a user can interact with. So if it isn't visible to a user, you shouldn't be able to interact with it. So, it's feature, not a bug. :)

That being said, it isn't clear from your post what action is causing the error. This code will wait for the select list to become visible before you try to select an option inside it:

```
b.link(class: 'btn-open-filers').when_present.click
b.div(class: 'form-group').wait_until_present
b.select_list(name: 'bedroomsMin").select '3+ Beds'
```

Justin's answer is functionally the same as this, and `when_present` is probably more elegant.